# Distribution of $\min_{j\ge 1}(X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_j)/j$ when $X_i$'s are i.i.d $\text{Exp}(1)$

Tags: distributions, uniform-distribution, exponential-distribution, extreme-value

Suppose $(X_n)_{n\ge 1}$ is a sequence of independent Exponential random variables with mean $1$. I am trying to find the distribution of $\min_{j\ge 1}(X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_j)/j$.

Simulation suggests the distribution is uniform on $(0,1)$.

Define $S_j=X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_j$ and $Y_n=\min_{1\le j\le n}\left\{\frac{S_j}{j}\right\}\,,\,n\ge 1$.

My idea was to find the limiting distribution of $Y_n$ as $n\to \infty$.

For $u\ge 0$, I have

\begin{align}
P(Y_n\ge u)&=P(S_1>u,S_2>2u,\ldots,S_n>nu)
\\&=\int P(S_1>u,S_2>2u,\ldots,S_n>nu \mid S_n=t)f_{S_n}(t)\,\mathrm dt
\\&=\int_{nu}^\infty P(S_1>u,S_2>2u,\ldots,S_{n-1}>(n-1)u \mid S_n=t)f_{S_n}(t)\,\mathrm dt
\\&=\int_{nu}^\infty P\left(\frac{S_1}{S_n}>\frac{u}{t},\frac{S_2}{S_n}>\frac{2u}{t},\ldots,\frac{S_{n-1}}{S_n}>\frac{(n-1)u}{t}\right)f_{S_n}(t)\,\mathrm dt
\end{align}

The last equality holds because $\left(\frac{S_i}{S_{n}}\right)_{1\le i\le n-1}$ is independent of $S_n$.

I think the vector $\left(\frac{S_i}{S_{n}}\right)_{1\le i\le n-1}$ has the same distribution as the order statistics of $(U_i)_{1\le i\le n-1}$ where $U_i$'s are i.i.d uniform on $(0,1)$. And $S_n$ of course has a Gamma distribution.

But working out the exact cdf of $Y_n$ for fixed $n$ looks cumbersome. Is there another way of finding the limiting distribution of $Y_n$ or maybe a different approach altogether?

Comment: I don't understand the comment "Simulation suggests the distribution is uniform on (0,1)." This appears to be the case as $n$ tends to infinity, but that is not how the problem is stated. The problem is stated that there is a sample of size $n$. And based on my simulations (assuming I understood the problem correctly), it is far from Uniform for finite $n$, and even with $n = 200$, it has not converged to Uniform.

Comment: @wolfies There is no $n$ in the statement of the problem. I added the $n$ thinking that what I am trying to find is a limiting distribution as $n\to \infty$. My simulation was based on this understanding, but perhaps I made a mistake.

Comment: The opening line states $X_n$ is a sequence, presumably of length $n$. It further states $n \ge 1$. If $n= 1$, the distribution of the desired _min_ is self-evidently Exponential and not Uniform.

Comment: @wolfies Sorry, I wasn't referring to that $n$. That $n$ is meant to be a dummy index; it is the same as $(X_j)_{j\ge 1}$. This is an infinite sequence.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376819/the-min-of-the-mean-of-iid-exponential-variables

Answer (score 3):

This response does not give you the limiting distribution of $Y_n$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ but it does give you the pdf of $Y_n$ for any value of $n \geq 1$.

For small values of $n$, *Mathematica* will give you the pdf for $Y_n$:

```
n = 3;
dist = TransformedDistribution[Min[Table[Sum[x[i], {i, j}]/j, {j, n}]], 
   Table[x[i] \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[1], {i, n}]];
PDF[dist, z][[1, 1, 1]]
```

$$\frac{1}{2} e^{-3 z} \left(9 z^2+6 z+2\right)$$

After looking at several values of $n$ a pattern is apparent and found with the use of the `FindSequenceFunction` function (similar to looking things up on [oeis.org](https://oeis.org/)).  The pdf for any value of $n$ and $y_n \ge 0$ is $\frac{\Gamma (n,n y_n)}{\Gamma (n)}$:

```
pdf[n_, y_] := Gamma[n, n y]/ Gamma[n]
```

where `Gamma[z]` is the Euler gamma function and `Gamma[a, z]` is the incomplete gamma function.

It might be possible to determine the limiting values of the pdf as $n \rightarrow \infty$.  But to show how the limiting pdf is approached with increasing values of $n$ one can create an animation or a grid of figures:

```
p = ConstantArray[0, 20];
k = 0;
Do[k = k + 1;
 p[[k]] = 
  Show[ListPlot[{{1, 0}, {1, 1}}, Joined -> True, 
    PlotStyle -> LightGray, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 1}}, 
    Frame -> True, PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
    FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 11, Black] &) /@ 
    {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(Y\), \(n\)]\)", "Density"}, 
    PlotLabel -> Style["n = " <> ToString[n], Bold, 14]],
   Plot[pdf[n, y] // Quiet, {y, 0, 2}]], 
     {n, Flatten[Join[Range[5], Range[10, 50, 10], Range[100, 500, 100], Range[1000, 5000, 1000]]]}]
GraphicsGrid[{p[[1 ;; 5]], p[[6 ;; 10]], p[[11 ;; 15]], 
  p[[16 ;; 20]]}, ImageSize -> 1000, Spacings -> {-75, 0}]
```

[image: Grid of density plots showing change in distribution as n gets large]

Comment: +1. Clearly the limit of the pdf is the uniform pdf on $[0,1],$ as speculated in the question. One simple proof applies Chebyshev to the Gamma$(n)$ distribution.  It would also help to explain *Mathematica's* notation:  `Gamma[a,x]/Gamma[a]` is the *survival* function of a Gamma$(a)$ distribution evaluated at $x.$  Finally, the animated gif is causing occasional faults in this browser (and is very distracting).  It's pleasanter to review a faceted panel of graphics rather than an animation.

Comment: @whuber My objective was to supply the pdf of $Y_n$ (as it was mentioned that the cdf might be cumbersome) and not deal with any proofs of the limiting distribution.  If you let me know the name of the browser that's causing trouble, I can see if I can produce a less bothersome animation.  I used *Mathematica* because I know the OP has access to it but you're definitely correct in that I need to add a better description of the notation for others.